# Configuration reload with Jakarta Commons Daemon

Tags: java, apache-commons-daemon

Using [Jakarta Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/index.html) is it possible to have my Java application perform an action (reload a configuration) when a `SIGHUP` signal is sent to the `jsvc` process? If not - what are my other options for reloading the configuration with this library - without stopping the process? I have looked at the documentation but didn't find it that clear on this issue.

**Note:** I do not require a cross-platform way of handling signals. I just want to know what Jakarta Commons Daemon offers in terms of configuration reloading when used with a UNIX based platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't have a cross-platform way to handle signals. Your best bet is to open a `Socket` and wait for some input on it. Use `netcat` or a small Java program to connect to the socket. Inside, accept the connection, reload and close the connection. You don't even need to send data back and forth.

[EDIT] There doesn't seem to be any support to handle signals in the C part of Jakarta Commons Daemon. See this [article from IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/i-signalhandling/) how to implement your own signal handler in a JNI library. It was written for Java 1.3 but is still valid for Java 5 and 6.

[EDIT2] If portability is not an issue, you can try the undocumented and unsupported class `sun.misc.Signal`. See [this thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?trange=15&threadID=514860&forumID=4&tstart=30). Note that it's unsupported, undocumented, etc. and the API didn't change for the past five years.

Comment: Hi, that wasn't my question. I don't require a cross platform way to handle signals. I am interested only in how this is achieved with  Jakarta Commons Daemon.

Comment: I understand. My answer is: JCD doesn't help in your case and the Java VM doesn't offer any other options.